# Jquery mobile 1.4 on iOS the fixed elements on bottom of page hide input text onfocus

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios7, focus, blur, cordova-3

Hi there I am building cordova 3 app with Jquery mobile 1.4

Safari, and Chrome on my mac have no issues with the following, but when I deploy on the real device, or iOS simulator and want to type in the fields I get the bottom fixed elements of the page moving up and overlapping the input elements. The cursor is blinking in the right position, where the input field is, but the slider of the footer is hiding it.

To make it simple my page looks like that:

[header fixed]
div with input text
div with input text
div with input text
[footer fixed]

one of the input text instances

```
<input data-role="none" class="inputCalc gray_br" type="text" id="grams4" value="37"><div class="macro_g">grams</div>
```

the slider on the bottom

```
<div id="cal_slider" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; height:57px; width:100%; background-color:#E2E2E2;">
<form style="padding-top:6px" class="full-width-slider"><label for="slider-12" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Slider:</label> <input type="range" data-highlight="true" name="slider-12" id="slider-12" min="0" max="100" value="50"></form>
</div>
```

Jquery to show hide on focus and blur events

```
$(document).on('focus', 'input , text', function(e){

    // I have try with --> $("#grams4").focus( function () {... // but it's the same

    console.log("on focus fired");

    $("#cal_slider").hide();

});


$(document).on('blur', 'input, text', function(e){

    console.log("on blur fired");

        $("#cal_slider").show();

});
```

So I have been trying with **focus()** and **blur()** events to toggle (show and hide) the slider. It works fine on Chrome and Safari.

But on real device (iPhone 5 iOS7) when I tap the input textfield, the cycle works like expected the first time only:

(1) I get a focus log, the footer is hidden, (2) the keyboard comes up and (3) I can type in the input text.

Then (4) when I tap DONE the keybord hides and it's OK. (5) I get a blur event in the console, and the footer with the slider shows again. Perfect.

However, if I tap again on any of the input text fields, I get a blur log in the console and not a focus as expected, and the slider goes back again in front of the input field.

As I told above in Chrome, Safary works perfectly.

Any other ideas how to detect keybord on / off, maybe without event handlers ?

Comment: try this solution here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5j8RL/, it works on iPhone 5. When you set `bottom: 0px` you actually hide the slider underneath the footer.

Comment: Hmm, Omar, first, thank you for the code sample. The project is based on multipage on one single html. I have a global footer that I have to hide when I get into this page, complicating the things, but I am going to apply your concept. Sounds good.

Comment: are you hiding footer using `data-tap-toggle="true"`?

Comment: hiding footer with $("[data-role=footer]").hide(); on 'pagecreate','page4'.

Anyway, I adapted your method, but I get to the same result. I think the problem is related with the fact I'm working in a page actually without the global JQM footer and header that I'm showing in the other pages.

In this page4 it is the main ui-content only. My footer is not a role=footer but a fixed div with the slider in it.

The page is a calculator tool fully stuffed with elements. Need space.

If I load the whole thing in the iOS simulator Safari, no problem. But once on device... overlapping.

Comment: can you post your markup here on create a fiddle?

Comment: I will try some other options then will fiddle it, even though it is a lot of code to reproduce the whole process.

BUT !!! 
the input text fields

Comment: FOUND A SOLUTION HERE !!! Now the world is different. Thank you OMAR for support and ideas.

So... put the following code after the closing </body> tag of the multipage.

<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write( '<style>#footer{visibility:hidden}@media(min-height:' + ($( window ).height() - 10) + 'px){#footer{visibility:visible}}</style>' );
    </script>

Thanks to Richard Kennard http://stackoverflow.com/a/20092755/3166158

Answer (score 0):

This works:

put the following code after the closing  tag of the multipage.

```
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write( '<style>#footer{visibility:hidden}@media(min-height:' + ($( window ).height() - 10) + 'px){#footer{visibility:visible}}</style>' );
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks to Richard Kennard [stackoverflow.com/a/20092755/3166158](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20092755/3166158)