# How to get media query to recognize landscape orientation?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I have a JQM app with a fixed footer.  In order to get around a rendering issue when the keyboard is shown, I found some CSS3 media queries that set the visibility of the .ui-footer-fixed class to visible if the min-height of the screen is more than a certain number of pixels based on the orientation.

The portrait mode screen size and orientation is detected correctly and shows/hides the class as I would expect when the keyboard is displayed and hidden.  When in landscape mode, however, the landscape orientation is not detected and the default visibility of hidden takes over.

This is the pertinent script that sets up these media queries:

```
var win = $(window),
    height = win.height(),
    width = win.width();

document.write([
    "<style>",
    ".ui-footer-fixed { visibility: hidden; }",
    "@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-height: " + (Math.max(width, height) - 10) + "px)",
    "{ .ui-footer-fixed { visibility: visible; }",
    "@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-height: " + (Math.min(width, height) - 30) + "px)",
    "{ .ui-footer-fixed { visibility: visible; }",
    "</style>"
].join(" "));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Media queries aren't supposed to care about orientation. They can detect screen size, screen resolution, and whether there's a screen or printout. Perhaps you can use JavaScript to detect whether or not a form element is focused (implying the keyboard is shown)? Or, since you're using JavaScript, simply check if `win.width() > win.height()` -- if it is, you're in landscape mode.

Comment: Easy way, listen to `orientauonchange` event, if landscape, unfix both toolbars.

Comment: but the browser (either Chrome in iPhone5 emulation mode, or an actual iPhone) does respond to changing from portrait to landscape because the fixed footer appears and disappears when I toggle the orientation.  It just doesn't appear to be able to match my landscape media query.  FWIW, this happens whether I load the page with the device in landscape or if I change orientation after I load the site.

Comment: So you want to hide footer only when orientation is landscape?

Comment: I've made this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/X2HB8/) and tested it on iPhone 5 for both Safari and Chrome. It performs as it should on Safari, but not on Chrome. I dont know why Chrome isn't dealing with `display: none;` well.

Comment: No, I want the fixed footer to be hidden when the keyboard is displayed, because JQM (at least on iPhone) doesn't re-render the fixed footer very well in response to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lay in the original solution I tried, but there were some closing curly braces missing from the two @media queries.

The solution came from this SO post: [jquery-mobile-hide-fixed-footer-when-keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069352/jquery-mobile-hide-fixed-footer-when-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question how to get media query to recognize landscape orientation?

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
   body
   {
      background: red;
   }
}
```